# Spring OAuth2 asking for password when sending refresh token

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have been trying to use OAuth2 for the first time with Spring Boot.

The infrastructure is working, however, when the authorization token is expired and I send the refresh token to get a new one, I am also being asked for username and password.

*The question: shouldn't the refresh token be enough to get a new authorization token? Otherwise I would need to store the user credentials, which does not sound right.*

***Is this something I am totally getting wrong?***

Thanks!

**My ResourceServer config:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuth2ConfigResource extends 
ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .requestMatchers()
              .antMatchers("/**")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()               
              .antMatchers("/api/secure/**")
                .access("#oauth2.clientHasRole('ADMIN')")
              .antMatchers("/api/public/**")
                .access("#oauth2.clientHasRole('USER')");
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
    resources.tokenStore(tokenStore());
  }

  @Bean
  public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
  }

  @Bean
  public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    return tokenConverter;
  }
}
```

**My AuthServer config:**

```
@Configuration
```

@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("userDetailsService")
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

private int expiration = 60;

@Bean
@Autowired
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(@Value("${jwt.secret}") String secret) {
    return new StandardPasswordEncoder(secret);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
    oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
    configurer.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    configurer.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {                

    clients.inMemory()
    .withClient("user1")
    .secret("pass1")
    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(expiration)
    .authorities("ADMIN", "USER")
    .scopes("read")
    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token", "client_credentials")
    .and()
    .withClient("user2")
    .secret("pass2")
    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(expiration)
    .authorities("USER")
    .scopes("read")
    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token", "client_credentials");
}
```

}

**The usage:**

*1. Aquiring the token*

```
curl -X POST --user 'user2:pass2' -d 'grant_type=password&username=user2&password=pass2' http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
```

*2. Reaching the API*

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer 260480f7-3e94-4811-a49d-b385dff83f4a" http://localhost:8080/api/public/request/felipe
```

*3. Using the refresh token to get a new auth token*

```
curl -X POST --user 'user2:pass2' -d 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=48c9f1db-9252-47a0-9a28-091caa775e4c' http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
```

As mentioned, this infrastructure works perfectly, however, I do not understand why I should pass the credentials (assuming there's no workarounds) when using refresh tokens, since this token is there just to prevent - to the best of my understanding - the exposition of credentials.

Comment: test on the test all in samples? share ur config? by editing your question

Comment: which flow did you generate the access_token with ?

Comment: @tgkprog the configs are there.

Comment: @Gab, I'm using the password flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. User Credentials

`username` and `password` are parameters to specify **user credentials** (user ID and password).

```
grant_type=password&username={User-ID}&password={Password}
```

#### 2. Client Credentials

`Authorization` header included in requests to the token endpoint contains **client credentials** (client ID and client secret).

```
--user '{Client-ID}:{Client-Secret}'
```

#### 3. Recommendation

You should change the following code:

```
.withClient("user2")
.secret("pass2")
```

to

```
.withClient("clientId2")
.secret("clientSecret2")
```

to avoid confusion.